# How to use pointers to change values inside a method

Tags: c, pointers

```
void change (char *a, char *b, char *c, char *d, char *e) {  
temp = *a;
*a = *temp;
*b = *a;
*c = *b;
*d = *c; 
*e = temp;
}
```

I've been calling this method to try to switch around the character order, but every time i call it, the result is:

> Original: abcde
>   1st call: acdee
>   2nd call: adeee
>   3rd call: aeeee
>   4th call: aeeee

It's meant to swap 5 characters every time. The fifth to the fourth and the fourth to the third and so on. The first is also supposed to switch to the fifth -

```
Input  : abcde  
Output : bcdea
```

I can't figure out what I've done wrong here. Could someone find out what's wrong with the code here?

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: Indeed - we have to know what result you are expecting to offer a solution.  The code obviously does exactly what you told it to do.  You naturally want it to do something different.  What, exactly, is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you mean the following

```
void change (char *a, char *b, char *c, char *d, char *e) 
{  
    char temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = *c;
    *c = *d; 
    *d = *e;
    *e = temp;
}
```

or in the reverse order

```
void change (char *a, char *b, char *c, char *d, char *e) 
{  
    char temp = *e;
    *e = *d;
    *d = *c;
    *c = *b; 
    *b = *a;
    *a = temp;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear what you meant to say, But it looks like to want to move them in cyclic order. So this will work

```
void change (char *a, char *b, char *c, char *d, char *e) {  

char temp = *a;
*a = *b;
*b = *c;
*c = *d;
*d = *e; 
*e = temp;
}
```

Comment: It may be helpful to explain why OP's method does not work - where is the error?

Answer (score 0):

This is how the function should be:

```
void swap(chat *a, char *b)
{
   char tmp = *b;
   *b = *a;
   *a = tmp;
}
```

You don't need to pass 5 arguments to it; only 2, which are the two characters you want to swap.

And don't dereference the `tmp` variable, since it is not a pointer.

Comment: Wow.  Can you read OP's mind?  How do you know this is what they are trying to do?

Comment: The OP said they want to change around the order, which means they want to swap

Comment: That's not what their code looks like to me.  I see something with five arguments that is perhaps trying to perform a rotate.  I wasn't asking - I know you can't know what OP is trying to do.  There isn't enough information.  I just wanted you to think about it.

Comment: Sorry about that, It's meant to swap 5 characters every time. The fifth to the fourth and the fourth to the third and so on. The first is also supposed to switch to the fifth

Comment: @okbuthow I've edited your question with the expected result you have just provided.  It is important to add these details in your question.